# What's in the http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2 namespace?

Tags: web-part, list-form

I'm adding some custom forms to a list instance by [using the `<AllUsersWebPart>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544142.aspx) element in the list schema. It basically configures a WebPart.

My question is, what are all the possible tags I can use in there. What's in the http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2 namespace?

There are also variations of this, like http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm.

Where can I find a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's allways an XML-serialized webpart or something very similar. Look for ListFormWebpart class definition from MSDN:

```
[DesignerAttribute(typeof(SPControlDesigner))] 
[XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/ListForm")] 
[SupportsAttributeMarkupAttribute(false)] 
[AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Level=AspNetHostingPermissionLevel.Minimal)] 
[SharePointPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, ObjectModel=true)] 
public sealed class ListFormWebPart : WebPart, IDesignTimeHtmlProvider, IDesignerEventAccessor
```

Note the namespace. So I think it may be any of webparts in Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages at least (in XML-serialized form). And look at example:

```
<AllUsersWebPart WebPartZoneID="Right" WebPartOrder="1">
         <![CDATA[
            <WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2" xmlns:iwp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2/Image">
               <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
               <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ImageWebPart</TypeName>
               <FrameType>None</FrameType>
               <Title>Site Image</Title>
               <iwp:ImageLink>/_layouts/images/homepage.gif</iwp:ImageLink>
            </WebPart>
          ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
```

Note "CDATA" - it means that there's no any XML scheme or other way to view a list of all available elements inside AllUsersWebPart tag because there's no such explicit restriction.

Comment: I figured as much, but something checks for the XML validity (even if inside CDATA). So It must be a schema or some rules somewhere. I can't imagine it just tries to deserialize the XML as a webpart and hope it sticks...

Comment: Please examine for example SPSolutionExplorer.GetFilesInFolderTree method. For example, note this line: limitedWebPartManager.ExportWebPart(webPart, (XmlWriter) new XmlTextWriter((TextWriter) stringWriter). The output is used as serialized string. And if you look for details of SPLimitedWebPartManager.ExportWebPart method you'll see - it seems there's no explicit restrictions. I think SHarePoint relies on XML serialization, if it works - OK. So it seems there's no hardcoded range of available elements inside AllUsersWebPart element.